# Default value assigned by .data() in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a default value assigned to an element when

```
var thisvar = $(this).data("somekey");
```

is called?

Sometimes I get "undefined" or "on" when I run

```
alert(thisvar);
```

Shouldn't the return value always be undefined?

Thank you!

Comment: You may have to provide just a little more code.  It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: It should always return `undefined`. Can you reproduce how you get `on` in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: @teneff Okay, I tried to recreate the error but it doesn't happen. On my project changing the name of the key from msflag to something else solved the issue. The value always returned undefined after that. Weird?

Comment: @Teneff: Unless there is a `data-somekey` attribute in the HTML...

Comment: OHH!!! That's why!! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery.data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore free from memory leaks. jQuery ensures that the data is removed when DOM elements are removed via jQuery methods, and when the user leaves the page.

Use proper system for jQuery data() function like this

```
jQuery.data( element, key )
```